# IOS: get file name in a directory

Tags: ios, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get all folders of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567711/get-all-folders-of-url)

I have this directory:

```
NSString *tmp = @"http://192.168.0.13/dev/doc/";
```

In this directory there is a pdf file called "file_01.pdf", is there a way to know name file if I have only path?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could be a wee bit more clear here.

1)

Is the name of that file already part of the path?

NSString has a very handy method called ["`lastPathComponent`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lastPathComponent) that may work well for you here.

2)

Or, if you have the parent folder path but don't have the names of the files just yet, you need to get an array containing the filenames within that folder.

Which you can do via a NSFileManager method named ["`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath%3aerror%3a) that you can use to get the contents of that folder.

Comment: yes I have the parent folder path and not the name of file inside, so I use contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: thanks