# IOS: file in a url directory path

Tags: ios, url, directory

I have this code but in NSLog I have ever a "null" result

```
NSString *tmp = @"http://192.168.0.13:8888/dev/";

NSError *error = nil;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:tmp];

    NSArray *properties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSURLLocalizedNameKey,
                           NSURLCreationDateKey, NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey, nil];

    NSArray *array = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                      contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:url
                      includingPropertiesForKeys:properties
                      options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles)
                      error:&error];

    NSLog(@"array:%@", array);
```

why?
the url is correct because with browser I can access at directory.

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567711/get-all-folders-of-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this might be a bit confusing, you're actually accessing a file with that URL.  When the webserver is asked for the contents of a directory where there's no index.html, it does a directory listing, and serves an HTML file of the files in that directory.  I'll bet if you used an NSData to access the file, you'd see a bunch of  links.

Comment: but I need only the file names inside this directory, Can I get it with NSData?

Comment: Yeah, you can, but it ain't easy.  You need to take the data returned from the server, pass it to a XML/HTML parser, extract the <a href="X"> links, and then use them to scrape the server.