# How to fetch all images from a remote directory in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have set up a server with a subdirectory e.g. /html/images and I would like to download all the images (when possible ordered by the date they were added to the directory) without knowing the names of the files.

How can this be done? What could be other solutions if this isn't possible?

I have searched for a solution but the already answered questions are pretty old now. e.g. [Get all folders of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567711/get-all-folders-of-url)

Comment: Set up a service with a REST API on the server perhaps? I think you’re limited in what you can do on iOS in this regard

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that on your IOS app.
The server should give you an API that provides you an array of images.